# Blackberry | keyUp and keyDown methods from MediaKeyListener not called when app in background

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, background-process

I want to handle long press (about 10sec) of volume button (volume up or volume down doesn't matter).

For this reason I used own implementation of `MediaKeyListener`

```
private class LoongPressKeyListener extends MediaKeyListener {

    public boolean mediaAction(int action, int source,
            Object paramObject) {

        System.out.println("::: action=" + action + ";source=" + source + ";object=" + paramObject);
    }

    public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int status) {
        switch (Keypad.key(keycode)) {
            case Keypad.KEY_VOLUME_UP:
            case Keypad.KEY_VOLUME_DOWN:
                System.out.println("volume keyDown");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.keyDown(keycode, status);
        }
    }

    public boolean keyUp(int keycode, int status) {
        switch (Keypad.key(keycode)) {
            case Keypad.KEY_VOLUME_UP:
            case Keypad.KEY_VOLUME_DOWN:
                System.out.println("volume keyUp");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.keyUp(keycode, status);
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason `keyUp` and `keyDown` method have been called only when application in foreground. `mediaAction` has been called only when app in background.

Can someone explain is this a correct behavior? And is it possible to handle long volume button press from background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is correct behaviour, but you **can** still get volume up/down events while in the background.  From the BlackBerry documentation for [MediaKeyListener (bold is mine)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/media/MediaKeyListener.html):

> Applications would create a concrete subclass of this class that
>   implements the methods defined in MediaActionHandler. Then, an
>   instance of that class can be registered as a KeyListener either by
>   using Application.addKeyListener() or Screen.addKeyListener(), which
>   will handle media key presses while the application is in the
>   foreground. Then, **the same instance of MediaKeyListener can be
>   registered using Application.addMediaActionHandler() in order to
>   respond to media key presses while in the background**, as well as media
>   actions from other sources.

So, you need to make sure to call [Application#addMediaActionHandler()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#addMediaActionHandler%28net.rim.device.api.media.MediaActionHandler%29), to add your `LoongPressKeyListener` instance.

Also, from the `MediaActionHandler` class API docs:

> **Media Actions from Background Key Presses**
>
> If a MediaActionHandler is registered via
>   Application.addMediaActionHandler() then it will be notified of media
>   key presses that occur while the application is in the background. If
>   the application that happens to be in the foreground consumes a media
>   key press then it will not be posted as a media action to media action
>   handlers. Invocations of mediaAction() resulting from background key
>   presses will have source==MediaActionHandler.SOURCE_BACKGROUND_KEY and
>   context==null.

Here is a sample for detecting volume up, volume down, and volume long presses while in the background:

```java
public class MediaKeyHandler extends MediaKeyListener {

    public MediaKeyHandler() {
        // use this to register for events while in the background:
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().addMediaActionHandler(this);
        // use this to register for events while in the foreground:
        //UiApplication.getUiApplication().addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public boolean mediaAction(int action, int source, Object context) {
        System.out.println("mediaAction(" + action + "," + source + ",context)");

        if (source == MediaActionHandler.SOURCE_BACKGROUND_KEY) {
            switch (action) {
            case MediaActionHandler.MEDIA_ACTION_VOLUME_DOWN:
                // handle volume down key pressed
                break;
            case MediaActionHandler.MEDIA_ACTION_VOLUME_UP:
                // handle volume up key pressed
                break;
            case MediaActionHandler.MEDIA_ACTION_NEXT_TRACK:
                // handle volume up key long-pressed
                break;
            case MediaActionHandler.MEDIA_ACTION_PREV_TRACK:
                // handle volume down key long-pressed
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;  // keypress consumed
        } else {
            // keypresses while app is in foreground come here

            return false;  // keypress not consumed
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I know of no way to detect a **10-second** volume key press *while in the background*.  In the foreground, both `KeyListener#keyRepeat()` and `MediaKeyListener#mediaAction()` get called repeatedly, as you hold the key, but not in the background.  The code I show above works with a long-press of about a second (not 10 seconds).

Comment: So, as I understood from your answer, I haven't chance to handle releasing volume button (and haven't chance to handle long press). correct?

Comment: @CAMOBAP, unfortunately, that's correct.  When in the background, you don't receive a key-up event, so you can't tell when the volume key press ends.  However, the VOLUME_DOWN event is different from the PREV_TRACK event, so you can handle long presses by listening for PREV_TRACK.  But, that *long* press is only about one second, not 10.  See the update to my answer for more.

Comment: I have no words to express my gratitude to you!) Your answers is always detailed and supported by reference to documentation. thank you ever so much!!!

Comment: @CAMOBAP, you're very kind!  You're welcome, and best of luck with your apps!